# Permission denied error while installing/updating package in Raspberry Pi

Tags: apt, raspberry-pi

I got an error message concerning a package, and I did run the recommended command with administrative privileges:

```
$ sudo apt-get -f install
Preparing to unpack .../libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common_2.31.1-2+deb8u7_all.deb ...
Unpacking libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common (2.31.1-2+deb8u7) over (2.31.1-2+deb8u6) ...
dpkg: error processing archive /var/cache/apt/archives/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common_2.31.1-2+deb8u7_all.deb (--unpack):
unable to create `/usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES/gdk-pixbuf.mo.dpkg-new' (while processing `./usr/share/locale/xh/LC_MESSAGES/gdk-pixbuf.mo'): Operation not permitted
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common_2.31.1-2+deb8u7_all.deb
```

Why is the permission denied for root user? How can I fix this? Thanks in advance.

```
$ apt-cache policy libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common:
Installed: 2.31.1-2+deb8u6
Candidate: 2.31.1-2+deb8u7
Version table:
 2.31.1-2+deb8u7 0
500 http://mirrordirector.raspbian.org/raspbian/ jessie/main armhf Packages
 *** 2.31.1-2+deb8u6 0
100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Trying this on a Raspberry Pi 2

```
$ apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 : Depends: libgdk-pixbuf2.0-common (= 2.31.1-2+deb8u7) but 2.31.1-2+deb8u6 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Does the fact that the `e` attribute is set when showing the attributes of the file with `lsattr` cause any problems?

I can't move the file manually either:

```
$ sudo mv gdk-pixbuf.mo gdk-pixbuf.mo.old
mv: cannot move ‘gdk-pixbuf.mo’ to ‘gdk-pixbuf.mo.old’: Operation not permitted`

$ ls -lh
-rw-r--r-- 1 root       root      17K Sep 15 17:07 gdk-pixbuf.mo

$ getfacl gdk-pixbuf.mo
# file: gdk-pixbuf.mo
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rw-
group::r--
other::r--

$ getfacl LC_MESSAGES
# file: LC_MESSAGES/
# owner: root
# group: root
user::rwx
group::r-x
other::r-x
```

Comment: Is your user in the `sudoers` group? Try running `sudo -l -U name` where `name` is your username. You should see printed the level of sudo access available.

Comment: yes is sudo user

Comment: added the output, seems normal for me

Comment: is it a **dpkg** that your trying to install?

Comment: To be honest, anytime I have an issue with a cache, I just delete everything from the cache except the cache directory its self. Its not a great practice to use, but usually a problem with a cache will stem from data saved in a file thats being cached. If your deprate, you can always give it a shot, especially if your only on a raz-pi.

Answer (score 0):

Try cleaning up your packages:

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Then run this again:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Also that directory looks like its part of the `language-pack-gnome-xh-base` package, so maybe a apt-get install of that as well.

Comment: autoremove does not work either, posted the result in my post for better formatting

Comment: Its a problem thats cached, if anything he should use ***`$ sudo apt-get clean`***